# Angular single selection list with Shift/Alt/keyboard support

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm developing a web application and within this application I'm trying to display a list of mails with identical functionality and look as the list of mails in outlook.

I need the items to be selectable by a mouse click. Each mouse click will change the selected mail:

**Functionality example 1:**

[image: Functionality example 1]

After a mouse click I need to be able to select more mails, using the keyboard (shift / alt / ctrl) and the mouse.

**Functionality example 2:**

[image: Functionality example 2]

In example 2, I chose 'Test 5' mail. Then I selected two more mails using shift+down arrow. The email whose content is presented should still be 'Test 5'. Also during the screenshot the mouse hovered over 'Test 2' email and therefore its style is different.

How would you develop such a list with angular material? Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated as I'm new to angular and angular material

Comment: You can use a Selection List for this: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists

Comment: @FrankAdrian I did look at the selection list but it seems like its purpose is for multiple selection. I'm looking for a single selection list with the possibility to select more items using Shift / Alt functionality.